# Write a description for $F(x+1,y,z)=H(z,F(x,y,z))$.

Tags: logic, recursion

> Write a description for $F(x+1,y,z)=H(z,F(x,y,z))$.

I was thinking of using composition: $\mathbf{C}(H,I_{3,3},...)$ where $I_{3,3}$ is used for the $z$ argument in $H$. But how do I finish this composition with the argument $F(x,y,z)$? Do I use identity?

Comment: Maybe you need [primitive recursion function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition).

Comment: Could you give me an example on where to begin for this? Writing the argument $F(x,y,z)$ seems very confusing to me...